# Tag paragraphs based on language and export only those in a certain language

Tags: beamer

I am making slides in Beamer for a presentation that I hope to give in two different languages. To keep my translations consistent, I would like to edit both forms of the presentation in one Tex document, like so:

```
...
if EN=TRUE: {
    \begin{frame}
    Here is some text in English.
    \end{frame}
}

if EN=FALSE: {
    \begin{frame}
    Here is the same text in Korean.
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
Here is an image that should appear in both versions.
\end{frame}
...
```

Here `EN` is some kind of boolean variable that I can configure at the beginning of the file to control which slides end up in the PDF output.

Is this possible?

Comment: put `\newif\ifen` in the preamble  and use `\ifen something\else other language \fi`  (and use `\entrue` or `\enfalse` to choose which to get

Comment: Would you mind posting a more fleshed-out example? This is giving me "argument of frame has an extra }" errors.

Answer (score 1):

The `comment` package can be used here. This package provides two commands `\includecomment` and `\excludecomment` that are used to define new environments to be included or excluded, respectively.

For example, to show only Korean frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{englishonly}
\includecomment{koreanonly}
\begin{document}

\begin{englishonly}
\begin{frame}
    Here is some text in English.
\end{frame}
\end{englishonly}

\begin{koreanonly}
\begin{frame}
    Here is the same text in Korean.
\end{frame}
\end{koreanonly}

\begin{frame}
Here is an image that should appear in both versions.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]